# How to run a .plt file inside all subdirectories with gnuplot using python?

Tags: python, subprocess, gnuplot

[My directory structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKufv.png), with a different .plt file at the end of each subdirectory.

I want to run those files using gnuplot. This is what I have:

```
directory = "./"
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.plt'):
            plot = subprocess.POpen(['gnuplot', '-p'], shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            plot.communicate("load '%s'" % (file))
            plot.wait()
            print(plot.returncode)
```

But this returns:

```
$ python3 messiah.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "messiah.py", line 115, in <module>
    plot.communicate("load '%s'" % (file))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1009, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 958, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
-p: 1: gnuplot: not found
```

**Edit:** At the end of each directory there is also a .dat file which the .plt file uses to form the graph. This is why I have to traverse into the directory where both files are, and then run gnuplot in cmd. If I try to load the .plt file from outside, it throws an error saying the corresponding .dat file can't be found.

I tried this:

```
    source = "/mnt/d/Darshana_Project/Data"
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk(source):
        if not subdir:
            file = [fi for fi in files if fi.endswith('.plt')]
            cmd1 = "cd \"%s\"" % (root)
            cmd2 = "gnuplot -p \'%s\'" % (file[0])
            command = cmd1+';'+cmd2
            plot = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, encoding='utf8')
            plot.wait()
```

But it just gives me a: `The system cannot find the path specified` recursively over all subdirectories.

Comment: Probably it is not a good idea to change the directory in gnuplot. Then you get the confusion you're getting. Simply give gnuplot the absolute path of the file, as I did in my answer, something like `ffname = os.path.join(root,file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me under using Python 3.6.3 under Win10. I hope you can adapt it to your operating system.

```
### start all gnuplot files in tree
import os, subprocess

directory = r'C:\Users\Test'
gnuplotpath = r'C:\Users\Programs\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot'

for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.plt'):
            ffname = os.path.join(root,file)
            cmd = '{} -p "{}"'.format(gnuplotpath,ffname)
            plot = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            plot.communicate()
            plot.wait()
            print(plot.returncode)
### end of code
```

Comment: My gnuplot path has a space bar in it. cmd is giving me a '... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' error. Is there anyway to circumvent it other than reinstalling gnuplot in another location with no spaces?

Comment: @PrajjwalDas I would try to put it additionally into single quotes `gnuplotpath = r"'C:\Users\Programs\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot'"` (not double quotes as I said earlier).